# Find Command excluding multiple directories and multiple file extentions

Tags: find

I have a folder with lots of files and folder. It contains many multimedia files (jpg, jpeg, mp4, mpeg). The directory also contains lots of sub folders.

I want to do two things :

1. Find the total counts of all files
2. Find the total size used by the files and folder.

I want to exclude files with some particular extensions, like exclude mp4, jpeg files. I also want to exclude a list of folders also. Suppose I have 1000 files and 200 folders. Out of these files, I want to exclude files with some particular extensions and some folders. Like if I have 26 folders named a-z, I want to exclude the folders named h, f, y and so on.

The final output, of the total number of files present and the size they occupy should not contain these files and folders.

I have made an effort towards it and 90% is completed, the command exludes all the files and directories present but it prints the folder name as well, I just want the file name in the output.

```
find . -type d \( -path "*/Make-Directory-Script-master" -o -path "*/pycharm-community-2020.3" \) -prune  -o -type f \( -name "*.zip"  -o -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.json" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.srt" \) -prune -o  -print
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. Could you give us some lines of example output of what you get **and** of what you expect so that we can understand better what you mean? (Edit your question and add it there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `-type f` before final `-print`

command looks like (folded fo readability)

```
find . -type d \( -path "*/Make-Directory-Script-master" -o -path "*/pycharm-community-2020.3" \) -prune  
    -o -type f \( -name "*.zip"  -o -name "*.pdf" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.json" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.srt" \) -prune 
    -o -type f -print
```

---

the original command (abridged and line numbered)

```
#1  find . -type d \( -path ... \) -prune  
#2    -o -type f \( -name ... \) -prune 
#3    -o -print
```

- in line 1, you select path from a list and `-prune` (that is stop finding), to find whole line 1 "`\(..\) -prune`" evaluate to true, so path matching pattern are skipped from output.
- in line 2, using a **or** conjunction ( `-o` ) you filtered out a list of extension and skipped them from output also.
- using a final or, in line 3, whithout `-type f` you print any remaining path, either filename ot directory name.

Comment: Can you please explain why adding this works, my knowledge regarding this is very low as I just learned about it the day before I posted the question

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, the last -type f specifies that only files will be printed. Conversly if I added -type d then only the directories will be printed. Am I correct in my assesment...

Comment: yes that's correct, you can filter further using `-user XXX` or `-mtime -10` etc ...

Comment: so after the last -type f -print -user xxx, this will print all the files which belong to user xxx. Am I correct..